# Send link via Classic asp CDO email

Tags: asp-classic

I'm using classic ASP and sending an email via CDO and i need to send the following as a link in the body of the email.

http://example.co.uk/Uploaded_Files/<%=RealFileName%>

```
> ' we are sending a text email.. simply switch the comments around to
> send an html email instead ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "<h2 align=center>"
> & "<a href="http://example.co.uk/Uploaded_Files/" " &
> Request.Form("filenamex") & "">View File</a>"
```

The above code come back with this error,

Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'

Expected end of statement

Comment: please post the code again, it is confusing to understand
anyway, I think there's an extra quotation mark her: `"<a href="http://example.co.uk/Uploaded_Files/" " &`

Comment: > ' we are sending a text email.. simply switch the comments around to
> send an html email instead ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "<h2 align=center>"
> & "<a href="http://example.co.uk/Uploaded_Files/" " &
> Request.Form("filenamex") & "">View File</a>"

Comment: please, edit the question with the code above

Comment: I think you're messing up quotations, try this:
`ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "<h2 align=center><a href='example.co.uk/Uploaded_Files/" & Request.Form("filenamex") & "'>View File</a>"`

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you.

Comment: I'm posting as an aswer, please mark as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```
<%
html = "<a href=""http://example.co.uk/Uploaded_Files/" & RealFileName & """></a>"

Set cdoMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

cdoMessage.From = "email_from@domain.com"
cdoMessage.To = "email_to@domain.com"
cdoMessage.Bcc = "email_bcc@domain.com"
cdoMessage.Subject = "subject"
cdoMessage.ReplyTo = "email_replyto@domain.com"
cdoMessage.HTMLBody = html

sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpserver") = smtp.domain.com
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "sendusername") = user
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "sendpassword") = pass
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 587
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpusessl") = False
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2
cdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.update

cdoMessage.Send

Set cdoMessage = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the extra quotation marks, try this:

```
ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "<h2 align=center><a href='example.co.uk/Uploaded_Files/" & Request.Form("filenamex") & "'>View File</a>"
```

Comment: unfortunately there are some users here that thinks some tag belongs to him/her, simply distributes downvotes to what thinks isn't right/good/pretty/etc, and don't even spend some time to leave a feedback